# Why does the ship in Dead Space carry babies?

Tags: dead-space

So after watching a stream, a question came up about the babies in Dead Space 1. One of the enemies are the babies that crawl on all fours, on the walls and ceilings, and have 3 tentacles that fire barbs at you. In Dead Space 2, these come from care facilities in the city, and in 3 they are dog corpses. But in 1, they are babies.

Basically, there is a section of the ship dedicated to maintaining the babies in stasis, for some reason. Is that ever explained? Is there any (in-game or canon) explanation as to why the Ishimura (a mining vessel in deep space) has a large collection of babies on board?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are talking about enemies called [Lurkers](https://deadspace.fandom.com/wiki/Lurker), their page on wiki says the following:

> They are usually created from human babies and infant-like organ banks used in biological prosthetic procedures, but can also result from infected dogs, as is the case of those found onboard Sovereign Colonies ships and the icy surfaces of Tau Volantis.

So in case of Ishimura I'm afraid the answer is they are from "*infant-like organ banks used in biological prosthetic procedures*". Sounds really creepy even without necromorphs. Why they needed that many of those? Idk, when you mine with plasma cutters some limb-cutting incidents may occur indeed.

Comment: Well there you go. Like you said, creepy - but it is very in-keeping with the rest of the game's aesthetic